# Property height 100% not working in Angular 7 + Electron 4

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, electron

I have a component jobs-table.component.html. Above level I have flex-direction: column;

```
<div class="jobs-table">
 ...
</div>
```

And style jobs-table.component.css:

```
:host {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.jobs-table {
  height: 100%;
}
```

In Crome v73 and Mozilla v65.0.2 height: 100% working good.
But in Electron 4 and Opera v58 not working !
I see only one way to fix this in my case use

```
height: calc(100vh - 15rem);
```

Are there others ways to fix this ?
Code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkipxs
Thanks advance

Comment: have you added html, body { height:100%} in you style

Comment: Yes I added html, body { height:100%} in my style

Comment: share the complete HTML structure, may be one of the nested structure doesn't have the height set to 100%. it would be easy to fix the issue, if you can reproduce it on https://stackblitz.com/, then we can have a look

Comment: I reproduce my problem
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkipxs

Comment: This is weird, as much as I know Chrome and Electron should share the same engine. Why don't you try opening a issue on github?

Comment: I got around this problem with help
`:host {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.jobs-table {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. 
I used `height: 1px;` for parent. And `height: 100%;` working well for child now.
I think in my case `flex-grow: 1;` have same behavior as `min-height: 100%;` that is why `height: 1px;` helped me fix my problem.

```
:host {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 1px; /* Required to make the child 100% of the flex-grow: 1 */
}
.jobs-table {
  height: 100%;
}
```